# ORA 12899 when exporting from Access to Oracle 11g

Tags: oracle, ms-access, oracle11g

I'm trying to export a bunch of tables from Access to Oracle 11g and ran into ORA-12899 error.  This error is complaining that the value is too large for column (actual 256, max 255).  I double check the original Access table and the data type is set to Text with max length of 255. I'm not too familiar with Access and its size validation, but shouldn't it validate the size when the data is written?  Should I set the length in Access to 254 and chop off the end?

Comment: HOw are you exporting/importing into oracle?

Comment: Which character encodings are you using, on both Access and Oracle?

Comment: I'm using ODBC connection to export the data.  I'm not too sure about the character encoding in both database.  I manage to get around the problem by dumping it to Excel first and use SQL Developer to import the data.